# Xampp Web Server and Android

Tags: android, xampp

I have my database on Xampp Server. I want to connect that server to my Android App.
All I found was write a PHP Script and use JSON.
I am unfamiliar with PHP.
I have a huge database with around 10 tables.
How to connect the both.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very new to server side connections you can go with a simple way without using any frameworks.

this is Just like calling a .php file which holds all your queries and manipulations and return the result.

The below link will be more helpful for you to write API and integrating them with android app.

[Android SQL connect using both wamp and xamp](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Wrote a pHp Script but not getting how to pass data from android to the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create APIs, which performs basic CRUD(Create, Retrieve, Update and delete) using any server side language that is known to you. You can use PHP, JAVA, C# or Javascript for creating such Restful APIs. There are plenty of online tutorials available to start with.